# XMLHttpRequest for refreshing a page on external call

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Say I have page1.html, and this is a queue list of people waiting to see me.

I have access to page2.html, which I use to see the list, and call specific people. When I click on a name on page2.html, page1.html is supposed to append a class to that person's name (which uses css3 animations to make it blink).

The example is lame, but you get what I'm trying to do here... I have read a little bit about XMLHttpRequests, and the 'onreadystatechange', but I'm not sure how this works...

Ideas...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do it like this. Have your page2.html update a database when you click on a person's name. You can flag that person in your database when you click on his name on page2.html

Now on the other end make your page1.html continuously query the database in the background in a JavaScript loop. On requesting the information from the database you can accordingly update page1.html

I hope you get it. Do let me know if there are any loop holes.

This link might be of help: [PHP long polling, without excessive database access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834829/php-long-polling-without-excessive-database-access/4835008#4835008)

Comment: Hey, Yeah... a JS (AJAX) loop did occur to me, but you see, I don't want an 'active solution', something that constantly keeps bothering the server... In the event that there're a million end users, they're each going to be sending calls to the server, and that's going to load the server... Isn't there a passive solution? Perhaps something that doesn't even require a DB?

Comment: @Abhishek -  i have updated my answer with a link you might helpful

Comment: Yes, Long polling is one of the solutions I have found... But I ended up using HTML5's Server-Sent Events... More information in my own answer... :-S

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the XMLHttpRequest to load data from your page1.html and display it on your page2.html accordingly. You would have to use the request on page2 and return the data on page1.

You can think of page2 as your frontend or client where you would have to interpret the information and display it (in your example display the list and change the class of the person), while page1 is your backend that provides the information for your page2.

For further information about XMLHttpRequests or the concept that it's used for I suggest you have a look at the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX

Comment: Yes, you seem to understand the problem, but the thing is, I can't setup a loop and expect page1.html to constantly keep pinging in to check "Hey, have you changed?"... Is there an alternative solution? Something that allows me to code Page2.html to communicate with Page1.html when a change has occurred?

Comment: With just javascript and HTML you don't have that option. The check will have to be initiated by the user's browser. You could implement that by calling the page1 every so often using setInterval() and grabbing the data. The other options depend on what other technologies are available to you. Here some links to give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074569/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to update page1 when you click on person's name on page2. I think there are some cases here:

1. page2 is a [dialog window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). When you click a name it can be directly manipulated on page1. No XMLHttpRequest needed here.
2. page2 is a pop-up window. Almost the same. This [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/672-Passing-Data-From-A-Pop-Up-Window-To-A-Parent-Window-Using-ColdFusion-And-Javascript.htm) may help you about this one.
3. page2 is a standalone page, in a different tab/window. Here you need an ajax ( XMLHttpRequest ). When you click on name, this action should be write down somewhere ( server-side, sql or something ), and page1 should check for any changes at some time interval.

Comment: I want to avoid time interval separated requests... that's essentially making the client communicate with the server every 5 seconds (for example) asking "Hey, have you changed?". Can't I get something the other way around, where comms are silent, until the DB updates, then it gets in touch with a parent function which dispatches updates to various, active sessions?

Comment: @Abhishek you have to use one of the first two options. Without refresh of the page or ajax call, this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I did get a fair number of responses, and while the majority of them required constant javascript pinging or somewhat roundabout approaches (such as Reverse AJAX or COMET, Long Polling, etc.), they each solved the problem.

Nonetheless, a little extra digging, and I found a nugget of tech that fits exactly:

HTML5's Server-Sent Events
(http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/)

This allows the client to declare itself as a 'recipient' of communication from the server, effectively reversing the 'Request first, serve later' approach that is dominant in web technology. The server can initiate communication with the client, without an initial request, allowing me to push updates to clients as and when they become available (such as DB changes).